# ImportError: no module named md5

Tags: python3

I followed this [tutorial](http://web.onassar.com/blog/2011/01/02/installing-python-3-1-3-on-ubuntu-10-10/) to install Python-3.1.3 on Ubuntu.
On the Terminal, I run:
`python3.1.3` , then `import md5`

I get this error: `ImportError: no module named md5`

Same problem when I run: `import hashlib`

How can I fix this problem ?

P.S. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306531/python-importerror-no-module-named-md5) does not work for me.

I installed all these libraries before Python3.1.3 installation:

zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev

Comment: Why would you use a link that clearly states "python 2.5" for python 3+?  You do know that they are incompatible?!

Answer (score 3):

md5 is (from the python docs:) "[deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html?highlight=md5#md5) since version 2.5: Use the hashlib module instead".

You need [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html). It is in the `zlib` module and that is in the [zlib1g package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/zlib1g) and/or [zlib1g-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/trusty/zlib1g-dev) package.

Comment: I installed glib1g-dev but I get this error when I import hashlib: ImportError: no module named md5. And Paramiko API (used by Python to use SSH) is still using md5 and it is supported in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39423562/111036) on stackoverflow.

In short:

`md5` is an object, and it has no `new` method.

```py
m=hashlib.md5()
m.update(bytes("text","ascii"))
print(m.hexdigest())
```

But see the original answer for details.